# Brackets in stylus

Tags: css, formatting, stylus, stylelint

Is it possible to make automate formatting of stylus and save brackets using stylelint and prettier? So main problem I have is that while I formating some file, all brackets are deleting from `.styl` files. I want to make curly brackets required to make it more similar to css.

My stylelint file

```
module.exports = {
  extends: ['stylelint-stylus/standard', 'stylelint-config-prettier'],
  plugins: [
    // add this plugin here:
    'stylelint-stylus',
  ],
  // makes the stylus files parseable.
  overrides: [
    {
      files: [
        'utils/Alphapet/**/*.{css,styl,stylus}',
        'patterns/Alphapet/**/*.{css,styl,stylus}',
      ],
      customSyntax: 'postcss-styl',
    },
  ],
  rules: {
    // add rules settings here, such as:
    'stylus/declaration-colon': 'always',
    'stylus/selector-list-comma': 'never',
    'stylus/semicolon': 'always',
    'stylus/single-line-comment': 'always',
    'stylus/single-line-comment-double-slash-space-after': 'always',
    'stylus/media-feature-colon': 'always',
    'no-missing-end-of-source-newline': true,
  },
}
```

versions

```
  "dependencies": {
    "stylus": "^0.54.8",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "stylelint": "^14.9.1",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^9.0.3",
    "stylelint-stylus": "^0.16.1",
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to add

```
rules: {
  'stylus/pythonic': 'never',
},
```

into your `stylelint.config.js` file. In this case it will always add brackets in your `.styl` files